# Does entity persisting populate id field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My question concerns id field population of class object after persising. Example question below this class example

```java
@Entity 
class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

Let's say I want to persist new entity to repo like this:

```java
SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(someArgs);
someEntityRepository.save(entity);
```

The question is - if I want to use id field, which in database is automatically generated, do I have to extract this entitiy once again:

```java
SomeEntity foundEntity = someEntitiyRepository.findTheEntitySomehow(someargs);
System.out.println(foundEntity.getId());
```

or I can use it right out of the box?

```java
// Copy code from above

SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(someArgs);
someEntityRepository.save(entity);
System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

Comment: Accepted answer isn't entirely correct. Save using persist depends on the implementation details behind the persist operation. If your sequence generator isn't DB driven, it can assign the value right away on the persist call without having to wait for the statement to need to be sent to the database to assign it. Hibernate's implementation of GenerationType.Auto causes it to delay allocation until the flush, but there are others that don't, and other providers that pre-allocate sequence numbers, obtaining them in batches and caching them is more efficient as it requires less DB statements

Comment: @Chris That's very useful if you have awareness of what is going on in the whole framework and have understanding of at least basic structure of every process like data persisting in the framework. I am not yet an experienced Spring developer, so I still have issues understanding how it all flows. Answer given was on point, and well enough for the purpose of my question. Nevertheless, your comment gave me some insight. I know remembered, that my repositories are interfaces and there's a lot more functionality present that I don't know how to use yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use repository save method Hibernate doesn't send a new record to the database until any flushing operation will be performed (like closing persistent context, or invoking JPQL statement).

To be sure that you will have an id, you have to invoke the flush manually. It can be called on any repository and all the persistent context will be flushed. Also `saveAndFlush()` repository method can be used.

```java
SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(someArgs);
someEntityRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

```java
SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(someArgs);
someEntityRepository.save(entity);
someEntityRepository.flush();
System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

Keep in mind that just invoking `save()` method will work too, if you don't have an open transaction (with `@Transactional` annotation). Because `save()` method will use own `@Transactional` with opening and closing persistent context itself.

```java
SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(someArgs);
someEntityRepository.save(entity);
System.out.println(entity.getId());
```

Comment: Op didn't open transaction before save function. So in this case save() function would persist object into database.

Comment: I didn't even realize at all that jpa repository doesn't flush objects automatically at all... You have probably saved my day

Comment: @Szprota21 Wait, so does it persist data if I never open transaction? I am quiet beginner at this stuff, so I only use jpa repository and barely add functionality to decrease complexity.

Comment: Yes, if you just do session().save() it should persist and flush data depending on your flushmode setting. By default if you won't open transaction it should be saved and flushed on save action

Comment: And also, does @DataJpaTest automatically turn all jpa manipulations into transactions? Because I know that it reverts all the changes after each test run

Comment: I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: @YuriyKirel Yes `@DataJpaTest` uses own transactions. So behavior of `save()` method will be different.

Comment: @v.ladynev Thank you, it's also important, because rn I am writing some test and don't have full awareness of what's going on, but you made it clearer for me